# TextView SetColor not working when fragment is loaded for the second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, spinner

I'm trying to change the color for my Custom Spinner selected item depending on which item is selected.

if I select the first element i want to set a grey color for the TextView because I'm using the first item as a hint message and the rest of items must be black.

when I'm trying the app and i load the fragment for the first time, it works in the right way, but when i used the navigation buttons to go to another fragment, if i switch again to the first fragment, the SetColor is not working, the Textview always appear with the text in black.

here is the code that i'm using to change the color in my fragment

```
sexoSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                if (v == null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_gender, null);
                }
                iSexoSelected = position;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.genderText)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gris_hint_fuente));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.genderText)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                        sexoSeleccion = "Femenino";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.genderText)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                        sexoSeleccion = "Masculino";
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

i don't know why the second time i load the fragment the color for the spinner is not changing, any ideas ?

thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: My guess is that you are are retaining the view hierarchy from the first instantiation of the fragment and are changing it when you should be changing the new hierarchy or vice versa . Your question has some ambiguity. Are you saying that the listener no longer works or that you expect the text to retain the color set? Posting your fragment/navigation logic might helpful someone take a closer look at your issue.

Comment: the listener is working, with debugging i found that the switch case option is '0', but the line ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.genderText)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gris_hint_fuente)); seems not be doing anything